# adding another else function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can someone please shed some light on this for me, i am trying to add another function into this javascript but not having much luck.

Heres the code:

```
<script>
$(".modcontentnewestmore").hide();
$('.morebutton').click(function () {
    if ($('.modcontentnewestmore').is(":hidden")) {
         $(".modcontentnewest").fadeTo(500, 0);
         $('.modcontentnewestmore').fadeTo(0, 500);

    } else {

        $('.modcontentnewestmore').fadeTo(500, 0);
              $('.modcontentnewest').fadeTo(0, 500);

    }
  });

</script>
```

Basically what i want to do is add another function like:

```
 $(".modcontentnewest").fadeTo(500, 0);
         $('.modcontentnewestevenmore').fadeTo(0, 500);
```

when the same button is clicked again a second time.

Is there a way of doing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly sure where you want it 
but you can make use of another variable to count how many times the button was pressed
if it is pressed 1 times add a number to the counter so if it is pressed again and the counter has reached a higher number do something else, again increase the counter or reset the counter.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) if you want to hide/unhide your element.

It could be something like:

```
$('.morebutton').click(function () {
$(this).toggle();
}
```

Note that this is untested code.